# Bootstrap Data Table - Different number of cells of rows with the same width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have a bootstrap (3.3.7) data table that I want to put the same width on all tds. Eventually, I would like to get all the rows with 3 cells to reach to the right side of the table keeping the same width in each cell. I did tons of research to find something like this but failed so any help with this would much appreciated.

The following screenshot is what I currently have: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/j033hYy.png]

And the following is what I would like to change my table to:

[image]

```css
.col-2 { width: 50%; }
.col-3 { width: 33.3%; }
.col-4 { width: 25%; }
.col-5 { width: 20%; }
.col-6 { width: 16.66666667%; }

table {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

thead tr th, td {
  text-align: center;
}

.td-parent {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">      
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="8">SPECIFICATION</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="2">Part Number</td>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="2">Position</td>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="2">Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="2">CDR1005</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="2">Front/Rear</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="2">4 identical pads</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-parent col-4" colspan="2">Meritor</td>
        <td class="td-parent col-4" colspan="2">Mercedes</td>
        <td class="td-parent col-4" colspan="2">Renault</td>
        <td class="td-parent col-4" colspan="2">WVA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="2">TBA</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="2">TBA</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="2">TBA</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="2">TBA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="2">A</td>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="2">B</td>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="2">C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="2">250</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="2">118</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="2">28</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1) Use `colspan` so cells take up entire row

- For 3 columns on a row use `colspan = 4`
- For 4 columns on a row use `colspan = 3`

### 2) Use `table-layout: fixed` to get equal widths.

The [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) property defines the algorithm used to lay out tables.  If it is not set, most browsers will default its value to `auto`, where width depends on content.  Therefore you are not getting equal widths for the cells.  **When you set this property to `fixed`, however, column width is determined by width, not by content**.

```css
table {
  margin-top: 50px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

thead tr th, td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1%;
}

.td-parent {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">      
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="12">SPECIFICATION</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">Part Number</td>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">Position</td>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="4">CDR1005</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="4">Front/Rear</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="4">4 identical pads</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">Meritor</td>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">Mercedes</td>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">Renault</td>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">WVA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">A</td>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">B</td>
        <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="4">250</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="4">118</td>
        <td class="td-child" colspan="4">28</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to have the rows with 3 columns reach to the right side of the table too, having the same width on rows with 3 columns is the problem.

Comment: My mistake!  Should be other way around.  I updated my answer.  (It was the class applied to some of your cells which was misleading.)

Comment: Rows of 3 columns still don't look even in width and neither do the rows of 4 columns to me

Comment: The solution is to use `table-layout: fixed` with a width on the cells, so that browsers respect your dimensions.

Comment: This is the beauty, solved the problem. Thanks.
Just wondering though, if column width is determined by width when `table-layout` property is defined, doesn't that mean I would need to set 33.3% width on each of 3 columns and 25% width on each of 4 columns? How did `width: 1%` do the magic here?

Comment: With `table-layout: fixed`, column width will be determined based on the first row of the table.  (i.e.  Your first row spans 12 columns, so column width is determined by dividing the width of that row by 12.)  However, if you do not define a `width` property on either the table, or table cells, browsers may ignore this rule because there is no set width based upon which to lay out the table.  (The truth is that in this particular case you don't need that `width: 1%` "magic", because you are using bootstrap, which already sets the width for the table.)

Comment: Oh right cool. Thanks for the information man that was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

- For th clspan = 12
- For 3 columns on a row use colspan = 4 (3 * 4 = 12)
- For 4 columns on a row use colspan = 3 (4 * 3 = 12)

---

Use this CSS:

```css
table{margin-top:50px;table-layout:fixed}
thead tr th,thead tr td{text-align:center}
.td-parent{font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th colspan="12">SPECIFICATION</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">Part Number</td>
   <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">Position</td>
   <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">Content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="td-child" colspan="4">CDR1005</td>
   <td class="td-child" colspan="4">Front/Rear</td>
   <td class="td-child" colspan="4">4 identical pads</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">Meritor</td>
   <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">Mercedes</td>
   <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">Renault</td>
   <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">WVA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
   <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
   <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
   <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">A</td>
   <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">B</td>
   <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="td-child" colspan="4">250</td>
   <td class="td-child" colspan="4">118</td>
   <td class="td-child" colspan="4">28</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: The same comment goes for your code too - I was able to have the rows with 3 columns reach to the right side of the table too, having the same width on rows with 3 columns is the problem.

Comment: Your problem has been solved. plz check the flowing code.

Comment: No, the rows of 3 columns still don't look even in width and neither do the rows of 4 columns. The problem has not been solved.

Answer (score 1):

control columns with `colspan`

```css
.col-2 { width: 50%; }
.col-3 { width: 33.3%; }
.col-4 { width: 25%; }
.col-5 { width: 20%; }
.col-6 { width: 16.66666667%; }

table {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

thead tr th, td {
  text-align: center;
}

.td-parent {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




<div class="container">      
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="12">SPECIFICATION</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td width="33.3333%" class="td-parent" colspan="4">Part Number</td>
            <td width="33.3333%" class="td-parent" colspan="4">Position</td>
            <td width="33.3333%" class="td-parent" colspan="4">Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-child" colspan="4">CDR1005</td>
            <td class="td-child" colspan="4">Front/Rear</td>
            <td class="td-child" colspan="4">4 identical pads</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">Meritor</td>
            <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">Mercedes</td>
            <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">Renault</td>
            <td class="td-parent" colspan="3">WVA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
            <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
            <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
            <td class="td-child" colspan="3">TBA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">A</td>
            <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">B</td>
            <td class="td-parent" colspan="4">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-child" colspan="4">250</td>
            <td class="td-child" colspan="4">118</td>
            <td class="td-child" colspan="4">28</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm already aware of that I can control it with colspan. If you closely look at your rows with 3 columns, width isn't the same in the columns.

Comment: I think you can add separate table within tr for getting 4col width same...

Comment: While separate tables may work, there's no need for it.  Use `table-layout: fixed` to get the browser to calculate cell width based on its width property rather than its content.

Comment: See my answer for working code, and see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) or [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-layout) for an explanation.

Comment: @ChavaG Great.. !

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinions, to make the same width of different rows making separate tables is the only way.

I hope this works.

```css
table { table-layout: fixed; }
.col-1 { width: 100%; }
.col-2 { width: 50%; }
.col-3 { width: 33.3%; }
.col-4 { width: 25%; }
.col-5 { width: 20%; }
.col-6 { width: 16.66666667%; }

.table-head
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-body 
{
     border: 1px solid black;
     border-top: 0;
     margin-top: 0;
     padding-top: 0;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     padding-bottom: 0;
}



tr, th, td {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.td-parent {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">      
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-head">
      <tr>
        <th class="col-1" colspan="3">SPECIFICATION</th>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-head">
      <tr>
        <td class="td-parent col-3" >Part Number</td>
        <td class="td-parent col-3" >Position</td>
        <td class="td-parent col-3" >Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-child col-3" >CDR1005</td>
        <td class="td-child col-3" >Front/Rear</td>
        <td class="td-child col-3" >4 identical pads</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-head">
      <tr>
        <td class="td-parent col-4" >Meritor</td>
        <td class="td-parent col-4" >Mercedes</td>
        <td class="td-parent col-4" >Renault</td>
        <td class="td-parent col-4" >WVA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-child col-4" >TBA</td>
        <td class="td-child col-4">TBA</td>
        <td class="td-child col-4" >TBA</td>
        <td class="td-child col-4">TBA</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-head">
      <tr>
        <td class="td-parent" >A</td>
        <td class="td-parent" >B</td>
        <td class="td-parent" >C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-child" >250</td>
        <td class="td-child" >118</td>
        <td class="td-child" >28</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Making separate tables works, but in my opinion, it's not the only way (or preferred way)...

Comment: You are right. There is one more way that I know is to define colgroup and calculate the width of col in each row by colspan...

Comment: Yes. I think that this would also need `table-layout: fixed` so that the browser determines column width based on defined width, and not based on content.